# How to install rotobezier in blender

Tags: add-on

Good day!
I have upgraded to blender 2.79 version but still unable to find the add on "rotobezier". Please help in this context.

Would be of great help.

Thanks ,

Sachin Sharma

Comment: Nothing on google?

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?322742-Blender-2-69-RotoBezier&p=2548292&viewfull=1#post2548292

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the link on @DuarteFarrajotaRamos' comment.

Rotobezier is part of blender now: It is no longer an addon and it does not have that name any more.

The functionality is part of how masks work.

To make dynamic masking, all that is needed is to create a mask and create keyframes for the control points. Also the control points for masks can be controlled using tracking points in the Movie Clip Editor.